# Shrink macro for case class

Tags: scala, shrink, scalacheck

I'm implementing [Shrink instances](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/wiki/User-Guide#test-case-minimisation) for my case classes. It seems to me that a macro could do the job. Has someone implemented one yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they have! [shapeless-contrib](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-contrib) has [an instance](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-contrib/blob/v0.3/scalacheck/main/scala/package.scala#L43) of [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s `TypeClass` for `Shrink`:

```
scala> import org.scalacheck._
import org.scalacheck._

scala> case class Foo(s: String, i: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> val unshrunk = Foo("This is a very long string", 1000)
unshrunk: Foo = Foo(This is a very long string,1000)

scala> implicitly[Shrink[Foo]].shrink(unshrunk) // boring default instance
res0: Stream[Foo] = Stream()

scala> import shapeless.contrib.scalacheck._
import shapeless.contrib.scalacheck._

scala> implicitly[Shrink[Foo]].shrink(unshrunk) // interesting instance
res1: Stream[Foo] = Stream(Foo(This is a ver,1000), ?)
```

This is supported by macros, but only the ones that Shapeless uses for its `Generic` machinery.

Comment: Thanks! It can even generate `Arbitrary`s.